# Adding Qt6/Pyside2 support in yocto image for x86/amd64 target with Intel CPU

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I'm trying to build a yocto image for x86/amd64 target with intel cpu. Meta-intel layer has given a bootable minimal x11 image-core-image-x11. I've to run a Pyside application on the target which would involve adding Qt5/6 support first and then adding PySide.

Following file results in bootable image but qmake command is not found

```
SUMMARY = "A full-featured basic X11 + PySide image."

LICENSE = "MIT"

IMAGE_FEATURES += " splash package-management x11-base"

DEPENDS += "qtbase"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "intel-corei7-64"

inherit core-image qt6-qmake features_check

REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES = "x11 ptest"

QB_MEM = '${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_FEATURES", "opengl", "-m 512", "-m 256", d)}'
```

Novice in yocto, trying to understand adding qt support without using boot2qt since boot2qt layer does not support MACHINE=intel-corei7-64

Answer (score 0):

It is not logic to include `qt6-qmake` in an image recipe type.

Image recipes `inherit`s `image.bbclass` which disables all package recipe's tasks from `do_fetch` to `do_package_*` tasks.

`qt6-qmake` has `do_configure` and `do_compile` for recipes that needs to run `qmake` on a Qt project.

In order to include `qmake` to your image:

1. Remove `qt6-qmake` from the `inherit` line.
2. Remove `DEPENDS += "qtbase"` as `DEPENDS` is for package recipes and not for image recipes.
3. Add:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " qtbase-dev qtbase-tools"
```